# Laravel news url is redirecting me to the home page everytime

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

Not showing any error just redirecting me to the homepage whenever I hit http://127.0.0.1:8000/news even I tried to dump under the function index but redirected me to the homepage

```
<?php
return [
    'news_route_prefix' => env("NEWS_ROUTER_PREFIX","news"),
    'news_category_route_prefix' => env("NEWS_CATEGORY_ROUTER_PREFIX","category"),
    'news_tag_route_prefix' => env("NEWS_TAG_ROUTER_PREFIX","tag"),
    'news_comment_route_prefix' => env("NEWS_COMMENT_ROUTER_PREFIX","comment"),
];

Route::group(['prefix' => config('news.news_route_prefix')],function(){

Route::get('/',[NewsController::class, 'index'])->name('news.index');
     
    });

public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $model_News = News::query()->select("news.*");
        $model_News->where("news.status", "publish")->orderBy('news.id', 'desc');
        if (!empty($search = $request->input("s"))) {
            $model_News->where(function($query) use ($search) {
                $query->where('news.title', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
                $query->orWhere('news.content', 'LIKE', '%' . $search . '%');
            });

            $title_page = __('Search results : ":s"', ["s" => $search]);
        }
        $data = [
            'rows'              => $model_News->with("getAuthor")->paginate(5),
            'model_category'    => NewsCategory::query()->where("status", "publish"),
            'model_tag'         => Tag::query(),
            'model_news'        => News::query()->where("status", "publish"),
            'custom_title_page' => $title_page ?? "",
            "seo_meta"          => News::getSeoMetaForPageList(),
        ];
        return view('News::frontend.index', $data);
    }

POST       news ................................................... news.comment.store › Modules\News\Controllers\CommentNewsController@store  
  GET|HEAD   news .................................................................. news.index › Modules\News\Controllers\NewsController@index  
  GET|HEAD   news/category/{slug} ................................. news.category.index › Modules\News\Controllers\CategoryNewsController@index  
  GET|HEAD   news/tag/{slug} ................................................ news.tag.index › Modules\News\Controllers\TagNewsController@index  
  GET|HEAD   news/{slug} ......................................................... news.detail › Modules\News\Controllers\NewsController@detail
```

Comment: Post a dump of your `php artisan route:list`

Comment: Checked many times it’s news

Comment: Kindly check in question

Comment: Yesterday it’s working fine but not now ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are redirected even making die and dump in index method that means the incoming request never be recieved in controller and in the **middleware** is redirected. Check what middlewares your route is using. Maybe it's a group middleware .
I hope this works.